# Deploy Test Pass Build to New Environment

Tags: azure, deployment, tfs, build-automation

Currently, I have automation script setup that takes latest source code from TFS, build package and deploy to azure.This works perfectly well for test site.However,My scenarios is like:

1. Deploy on Internal Test site
2. Perform Automated/Manual Test Mark
3. Mark current build as stable on BVT test pass (done through build quality in TFS)
4. Carry on Testing on new builds

My Problem is I need to deploy last stable build on UAT/Production as when requested.
I need some automation that perform build deployment using that stable build(package+config) instead of taking latest from TFS.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate tool for the job. Microsoft has a [release management offering](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx) that allows you to do orchestrate releases of specific builds of your software to the appropriate environments. It also will support Desired State Configuration in the near future.

The only piece of your scenario that it's lacking is integration with build quality -- you'll get the option to release all successful builds, regardless of quality.